# Should you use break in switch case loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement

Using FizzBuzz as an example, this switch case inside the for loop uses break after each case.

```
for (num = 1; num <= 100000; num ++) {
    switch (true) {
        case (num % 15 == 0):
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
            break;
        case (num % 3 == 0):
            console.log("Fizz");
            break;
        case (num % 5 == 0):
            console.log("Buzz");
            break;
        default:
            console.log(num);
            break;
    }
}
```

In Mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), they say that...

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures
>   that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is
>   executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If
>   break is omitted, **the program continues execution at the next
>   statement in the switch statement**.

I'm assuming what they mean is that when the script checks that num % 15 == 0, if there's no break and eventhough it matches true, it goes to num % 3 ==0 and so on. So then I did two tests with 100,000 numbers. One with the breaks and one without them.

I found about 2 seconds difference between break and no break, with **break shorter and faster.** But that's over many iterations.

My question is, does it really matter for most developers building small scale apps to use breaks in their loops? Is it a matter of habit and preference? Thoughts?

Comment: No, if there is no `break` - it will execute all the following `case` bodies unconditionally until the first `break` is met, or the `switch` block is ended.

Comment: It's not a mater of performance, it's a difference in functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a `case` condition is met in a switch statement it will execute all of the code blocks within that switch statement until it hits an exit command (think `break` or `return`). So the `break` is not only changing performance speed it's also changes functionality.

An easy way to think about switch statements is as alternative's to chained `if`-`else` statements.

your `switch` code can just as easily be written

```
if (num % 15 == 0) {
   console.log("FizzBuzz");
} else if (num % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
} else if (num % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
} else {
    console.log(num);
}
```

if you remove the `break;` statements you'll change how the code actually functions. It will perform more like

```
if (num % 15 == 0) {
   console.log("FizzBuzz");
}

if (num % 3 == 0 || num % 15 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
}

if (num % 5 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 || num % 15 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
} 

console.log(num);
```

The main difference being the lack of an `else` condition.

Comment: Callum when I put this is a jsfiddle, it does not do what I expect if your statement is true: https://jsfiddle.net/kty48k6p/. For example, the number 15 does not yield "FizzBuzz", "Fizz", and "Buzz".

Comment: @ka-mok my second code block should yield _"FizzBuzz","Fizz", "Buzz", 15_. just like your jsfiddle does. What might be confusing you is that the number is being logged after its associated "Fizz" and "Buzz" stuff. This is because `default: console.log(num);` is the last block executed.

Answer (score 2):

You get a different result with and without `break`. Without a `break` it passes through so on `num = 15` for example it will print out `"FizzBuzz"`, `"Fizz"`, `"Buzz"`, and `"15"`. Whereas with `break` it will just print out `"FizzBuzz"`. Having said that you don't need a break after the `default` case, if it is at the end of the switch.

Comment: Kindly re-read this comment! **"If you omit the 'break' statement, your program's logic is *different*** ... and, undoubtedly, ***wrong!"***

Comment: *"don't need a break after the default case"* ... assumes default is at end, but it can be anywhere in the switch. So if it's not at end it does need break

Comment: @MikeRobinson, what does this have to do with what I said?

Comment: @MikeRobinson not necessarily. Can combine cases with no break to execute one operation on purpose

Comment: "Technically true," Charlie, but "I'd be *(at best)* mightily annoyed with ye," if I actually saw such a thing in your source-code without an incredibly good reason.  **;-)**

Comment: Eli, have a look at my subsequent "Answer." (And, if you wish, down-vote it at your pleasure.)  "Hope this helps ..."  (Seriously.)

Comment: I ran both versions, with break and without break. They both print the same thing contrary to what you say. Whether "FizzBuzz" or "Fizz" or "Buzz" or the original num, it only appears once.

Comment: Nevermind you were right. I'm just really tired and misread the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you do *not* include a `break` statement, you have undoubtedly **introduced** **a** ***bug(!)*** into your program!

Here's why:

If you do *not* include a `break` statement, the logic will "simply fall-through" into the code for the additional conditions . . . **but it will *not(!)*** evaluate those conditions! It will simply crash right through, like the proverbial bull in the proverbial china-shop.

In other words, *without the `break` statements,* the case for `(num % 15 == 0)` would `console.log()` *four(!!)* (not "one") messages. Similarly, `(num % 3 == 0)` would log *three,* and so on.

*"Heh...* Don't go there."

=====
**EDIT:** It may be helpful to consider that the original *("C...")* concept of `switch` was that of "a multi-way `goto`" occurring at the *top* of the construct, which branched to one of the `case`-points within the body. The `break` statement generated a `goto` that sent you to the end of the `switch`. If you did *not* include it, the "helpful" assumption was that you *intended* to do what otherwise would happen:   that one `case` would simply "fall through" to the next one. (Which, absent `break`, is precisely what it *does.)* **"Caveat Coder!"**

Comment: That's not a bug at all. It can be desired functionality.

Comment: That's the thing, both with break and without breaking is yielding the same exact result. I'm running this on Sublime Text 3 with a custom builder using Node.JS

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Callum Morrisson's answer:

One case where you can remove `break` gracefully is when you are ***returning*** a value in a case.

For example,

```
switch(expression) {
    case x:
        return *something*
    case y:
        return *something different*
}
```

This does not cause fallthrough due to `return` breaking you out of the statement. You can think of `return` as doubling for a `break` in this example.

If you were to run a linter on a switch statement with both a `return` and a `break` within a case, you would receive an unreachable code error since the `return` is breaking you out of the statement before the `break` has a chance to execute.

```
// eslint
switch(expression) {
    case x:
        return *something*
        break; // error unreachable code
    case y:
        return *something different*
        break; // error unreachable code
}
```